# Equal length xtick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to have all the x-tick labels with equal length

```
f,a = plt.subplots(figsize=cm2inch(8.4,12))

boxdata = df.groupby(['type','det'])['res'].apply(list).to_dict()

box = a.boxplot(boxdata.values())

labels = [f"{text[0]:<9}{text[1]:>6}"for text in boxdata.keys()]

a.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Although all the strings in the list of labels are 15-character lengths, the labels are printed with different lengths. Is there anyone who has any idea about that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each caracter written as the same font size has a diffirent width. Even if there is 15 caracters, the labal cannot have the same size.

However you can align the label by the bottom as the following  code and  [the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQDO1.png):

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.transforms





f,a = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.4,12))

boxdata = [[4,4,5,8],[4,4,5,8],[4,4,5,8]]
box = a.boxplot(boxdata)
labels = ["aaaaaaa","AAAAAAA","iiiiiii"]

# Create an offset in the direction Y
dx = 0/72.; dy = -50/72. 
offset = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, f.dpi_scale_trans)

# apply offset transform to all x ticklabels.
for label in a.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + offset)

# apply a rotation and align in the bottom
a.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90, verticalalignment="bottom")
```